# HTML5 video tag play button not in center on mobile safari browser?

Tags: html5-video, mobile-safari

My web page HTML5 Video play button not showing in center on mobile safari browser?

My Code is

```
                Your browser does not support the video tag. 
              </video>
```

[This screen-shot on Mozilla browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9NHI.png)

[This screen-shot on Safari browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nba5u.png)

Comment: where is the code? You should show what you tried and what didn't worked?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh
My code is
<video id="paris_video" controls="" poster="/video_thumbs/1789300464.jpg" onpause="myFunction()">
                    <source src="/compressed/056BD459-876B-4A79-9057-1767A6EFA313.MOV" type="video/mp4">
                    <!-- <source src="media/last-time-race-start.ogg" type="video/ogg"> -->
                    Your browser does not support the video tag. 
                  </video>

Comment: You need to apply positioning CSS to display content in particular way. Right now its taking the browser's default placement which is top-left

Comment: @NitinSingh Thanks
But in other(Mozilla , Chrome) browser this play button on center for same code

Comment: I am having the same problem in safari.